# Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches with MySQL

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

After configuring kafka connect using the official documentation...

I get an error that the driver does not exist inside the kafka connect!

I got to try copying the `.jar` to the mentioned directory, but nothing happens.

Any suggestion for a solution?

docker compose

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:latest
    hostname: broker-1
    container_name: broker-1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_BROKER_RACK: rack-a
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: <netaddr>
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://<netaddr>:9092'
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9999
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: 'broker-1'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker-1:9092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

  schema_registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:latest
    hostname: schema_registry
    container_name: schema_registry
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker-1
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema_registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: 'zookeeper:2181'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN: '*'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS: 'GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS'

  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker-1
      - schema_registry
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker-1:9092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema_registry:8081'
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema_registry:8081'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars 
    volumes:
      - /etc/kafka/jars:/etc/kafka-connect/jars
```

driver

```
curl -k -SL "http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.tar.gz" | tar -xzf - -C /etc/kafka/jars --strip-components=1 mysql-connector-java-5.1.37/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar
```

curl

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{ "name": "quickstart-jdbc-source", "config": { "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector", "tasks.max": 1, "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/connect_test?user=root&password=confluent", "mode": "incrementing", "incrementing.column.name": "id", "timestamp.column.name": "modified", "topic.prefix": "quickstart-jdbc-", "poll.interval.ms": 1000 } }' \
  http://$CONNECT_HOST:8083/connectors
```

output

```
{"error_code":500,"message":"Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector', version='6.1.1-ccs', encodedVersion=6.1.1-ccs, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector', version='6.1.1-ccs', encodedVersion=6.1.1-ccs, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector', version='6.1.1-ccs', encodedVersion=6.1.1-ccs, type=connector, typeName='connector', location='file:/usr/share/java/confluent-control-center/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector', version='6.1.1-ccs', encodedVersion=6.1.1-ccs, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='file:/usr/share/java/confluent-control-center/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector', version='6.1.1-ccs', encodedVersion=6.1.1-ccs, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/confluent-control-center/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector', version='6.1.1-ccs', encodedVersion=6.1.1-ccs, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/confluent-control-center/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector', version='6.1.1-ccs', encodedVersion=6.1.1-ccs, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/confluent-control-center/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector', version='6.1.1-ccs', encodedVersion=6.1.1-ccs, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/confluent-control-center/'}"}
```

ls container

```
[root@connect appuser]# ls /usr/share/java/
acl       confluent-control-center  confluent-telemetry  kafka          monitoring-interceptors      rest-utils
confluent-common  confluent-hub-client      cp-base-new      kafka-serde-tools  mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar  schema-registry

[root@connect appuser]# ls /etc/kafka-connect/jars/
mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar
```

Doc: https://docs.confluent.io/5.0.0/installation/docker/docs/installation/connect-avro-jdbc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not saying your driver doesn't exist, it's saying the Connector doesn't. Scan over your error for each `PluginDesc{klass=class` and you'll notice the `connector.class` you're trying to use isn't there

The latest Kafka Connect images from Confluent include no connectors, outside of those pre-bundled with Kafka (and some ones from Control Center, which aren't really useful), so you must install others on your own - [described here](https://docs.confluent.io/home/connect/extending.html)

If you want to follow the 5.0 documentation, use the appropriate tagged docker image rather than `latest` (the old images do have the connectors installed)

Also, you would need to place the jdbc driver directly into the jdbc connector folder for it to properly be detected on the classpath; it is not a "plugin" in Connect terminology. The above link also shows an example of this

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to resolve it with your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the issue is related to the JDK version. If the driver class is compiled using JDK 11, attempting to load it using reflection with JDK 8 might result in errors. In this case, consider downgrading the version of Debezium.